# Rails - create an instance of a model based on another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am writing a todo app, which track often repeated tasks. I have a `CheckList` model which `has_many` `Task`s within it. Users can create a new `CheckList` and add Task to it as you normally would in Rails.

I would like users to also be able to create a checklist template (which would have its own Template model). This Template would be a representation (I'm thinking in `JSON`) of a `CheckList` and its `Task`s, and I would like to be able to create a new `CheckList` and populate it's `Task`s from it. That way they can just recreate the same checklist at different times.

**Is there an easy way to accomplish this?**

Is there any way to create a create_list_from_template method somewhere that would parse the template and create the `CheckList` and Tasks accordingly?

Am I going about this all wrong?
Any suggestions appreciated...

**EDIT**

I will use NestedAttributes to create the tasks directly from a CheckList and that is fine. What I am specifically asking, is how can I create a CheckList from a Template.

How would I call and pass the creation of this new `CheckList` based on the `JSON` data contained in the Template model?

Is there a way to create a different new action on the `CheckListsController`, to which I could pass the Template data? Like a `new_checklist_from_template` action or something?

Answer (score 2):

You should checkout `NestedAttributes`. It will allow you to create `parent` object and `n number` of child objects in one go. In your case `parent` is `CheckList` and `children` are `tasks`.

Check the following link

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: That is awesome, thanks. But how would I go about using that from the Template controller/model? Do I have to call a function that creates a new CheckList from the Template Controller? What action should that be?

Comment: There are many examples showing how to use `Nested Attributes` on the web. Here is the simplest example. https://coderwall.com/p/qwx3qa/nested-form-and-rails-4

Comment: To answer your question, you have to create new `Checklist` and pass the parameters for `tasks` as `tasks_attributes`